Getting token info using Dex scanner API
I am using the DexScanner API to fetch information about newly listed token pairs on the Raydium DEX. However, it takes around 30-35 seconds to retrieve the data once I receive the newly listed token address. I'm using TypeScript for this. Is there any other method to fetch the data faster?
